# I want to change the cursor over imported flash.swf

Tags: html, dreamweaver

How to change the cursor pointer to hand when my mouse goes over an imported flash.swf in dreamweaver?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

myMC.useHandCursor = true;